# Better way to test that a matrix is upper-triangular?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, algorithm, expression-test

Today, I got to thinking about how to test that a matrix was upper-triangular. So I had a try at it.

#### Algorithm

$\quad \quad a_{ij}=0 $  Or  $i \leq j$  $\Rightarrow$  $True$

My solution is

```
upperTriangularMatrixQ[mat_?MatrixQ] /; Equal @@ Dimensions@mat :=
  And @@ Flatten @ MapIndexed[#1 == 0 || LessEqual @@ #2 &, mat, {2}]
```

#### Performance testing

**Sample data**

```
testMat1 = UpperTriangularize@RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {1000, 1000}];
testMat2 = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {1000, 1000}];
```

**Test**

```
upperTriangularMatrixQ@testMat1 // Timing
```

> ```
> {3.151, True}
> ```

```
upperTriangularMatrixQ@testMat2 // Timing
```

> ```
> {3.978, False}
> ```

**My question**

Can you come up with a better performing algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like you are looping over all $i$ and $j$.  You don't have to even check the cases where $i \ge j$ That is worth a factor $2$

Comment: @RossMillikan, when $i > j $, the value of $a_{ij}$ must be zero.

Comment: @RossMillikan, with help of Mr.Wizard, I know that diagonal do not need to be checked.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I am always learning new *Mathematica* knowledge from your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did not specify if this test should be optimized for the positive or negative case.  If most of your matrices will fail the test it can be greatly beneficial to have an early exit behavior.  For example if the lower left element in the matrix is not zero you can fail the matrix after a single element test!  And even in the positive case the elements on or above the diagonal do not need to be checked.

Therefore I propose:

```
utmQ[m_?SquareMatrixQ] :=
  VectorQ[Range[Length@m - 1], m[[# + 1, ;; #]] == ConstantArray[0, #] &]
```

For earlier versions you can replace [`SquareMatrixQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SquareMatrixQ.html) with the original argument test and condition.

Timings:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

false = RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, {15000, 15000}];
true = UpperTriangularize[false];

utmQ[false] // AccurateTiming
utmQ[true]  // AccurateTiming
```

> ```
> 0.000029297
>
> 0.195
> ```

mfvonh's method for comparison:

```
upperTriangularMatrixQ2[false] // AccurateTiming
upperTriangularMatrixQ2[true]  // AccurateTiming
```

> ```
> 0.705001
>
> 0.795001
> ```

So you see that my method is four times faster in the positive case, and potentially orders of magnitude faster in the negative case.

Comment: I forgot that `diagonal do not need to be checked`.+1 :-)

Comment: @Tangshutao Are you running *Mathematica* 10?

Comment: ♦, No, just on `V8.0.1` and I got used to use that version

Comment: Dear Mr.W, I think your solution :`utmQv9[m_?MatrixQ] /; Equal @@ Dimensions[m] := 
 Null === Do[
   If[m[[i + 1, ;; i]] != ConstantArray[0, i], Return[1]], {i, 
    Length@m - 1}]` is faster then my algorithm.

Comment: @Tangshutao Okay.  I simplified my answer as the same (body) code will work in both versions, but you will need to replace `SquareMatrixQ` with your original argument tests, e.g. start with: `utmQ[m_?MatrixQ] /; Equal @@ Dimensions@m :=`

Comment: @Tangshutao I certainly hope it is faster. :-)

Comment: Ha! +1. I knew _somebody_ would bite :D

Answer (score 12):

Maybe

```
upperTriangularMatrixQ2[mat_?MatrixQ] /; Equal @@ Dimensions@mat := 
  UpperTriangularize@mat == mat;

test = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {1000, 1000}];
upperTriangularMatrixQ@test // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.126050, False}

```
upperTriangularMatrixQ2@test // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.003277, False}

```
test2 = UpperTriangularize@test;
upperTriangularMatrixQ@test2 // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.706272, True}

```
upperTriangularMatrixQ2@test2 // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.004966, True}

Comment: Good idea!+1,Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it can be done any faster

Comment: @belisarius Please see my answer. :D

Answer (score 1):

Since V 12.0 we have `UpperTriangularMatrixQ`:

```
testMat1 = UpperTriangularize @ RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {1000, 1000}];

testMat2 = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {1000, 1000}];

UpperTriangularMatrixQ @ testMat1 // Timing
```

{0.000803, True}

```
UpperTriangularMatrixQ @ testMat2 // Timing
```

{0.000018, False}